# How would I make a D3-style geo projection without D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm loading the entire D3.js library just for this:

```
d3.geo.mercator()
   .scale(s)
   .translate(t);
```

I'm not using anything else in D3 so I'd like to remove it as a dependency if possible. I looked in the D3 source code to try to pull out just the part I need to make my own projection function, but it's a bit of a labyrinth.

Can anyone give me a vanilla JavaScript version of the above snippet, without the D3?

In other words I want:

- a mercator projection function that takes a [lon, lat] and returns an [x, y] (same as D3)
- with a given scale `s` and translate `t` that work exactly the same as D3.

Comment: Doesn't the mercator projection itself provide the respective formula for such a conversion?

Comment: Right, but I would need a LOT of help understanding that, and I don't know how D3 implements 'scale' and 'translate'. Not everyone finds this stuff easy.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) does a fine job of explaining the mathematical calculations of the projection. D3.js scale and translate are just addition and multiplication. (Stack overflow isn't a site that writes your code for you.)

Comment: But I don't understand that notation on Wikipedia. I don't know where to begin. I'm asking for help, that's what this site is for. If you find my problem trivial then please go ahead and write me an answer, and you'll help me learn something.

Comment: @callum It used to be the case that you could get different parts of D3 separately, but it's not easily separable anymore. I don't see a disadvantage to including all of D3 though, it's a fairly small library.